# Can't create a delta lake table in hive

Tags: hive, delta-lake

I'm trying to create a delta lake table in hive 3.
I moved the delta-hive-assembly_2.11-0.3.0.jar to the hive aux directory and set into the hive cli

```
SET hive.input.format=io.delta.hive.HiveInputFormat;
SET hive.tez.input.format=io.delta.hive.HiveInputFormat;
```

but when I try to create the table it throws the following error:

```
[2b8497c1-b4d3-492e-80a5-ec4db4119018 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-133]: Exception occured while getting the URI from storage handler: Expected authority at index 22: deltastoragehandler://: Unsupported ex
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 22: deltastoragehandler://: Unsupported ex
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.DefaultStorageHandler.getURIForAuth(DefaultStorageHandler.java:76) ~[hive-exec-3.1.3000.7.1.7.0-551.jar:3.1.3000.7.1.7.0-551]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.command.CommandAuthorizerV2.addHivePrivObject(CommandAuthorizerV2.java:210) [hive-exec-3.1.3000.7.1.7.0-551.jar:3.1.3000.7.1.7.0-551]
```

The create statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.test_delta
( id INT, activ INT)
STORED BY 'io.delta.hive.DeltaStorageHandler'
LOCATION '/dev/delta/tessttt';
```

It's anyone that know why this error occurs ?

Comment: I am trying to create a delta table in hive 3 using the query mentioned in the accepted answer. I have a question on what should be specified in the location? Is it any path on the hdfs? does it have to be a path to an already existing delta table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the properties of the table the following: `TBLPROPERTIES('DO_NOT_UPDATE_STATS'='true');`

Example

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.test_delta
( id INT, activ INT)
STORED BY 'io.delta.hive.DeltaStorageHandler'
LOCATION '/dev/delta/tessttt'
TBLPROPERTIES('DO_NOT_UPDATE_STATS'='true';
```

The solution also works for iceberg format.
Inspired by: https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/issues/279

Comment: I am trying to create a delta table in hive 3 using the query mentioned in the accepted answer. I have a question on what should be specified in the location? Is it any path on the hdfs? does it have to be a path to an already existing delta table?